# Update woes: libstdc++6

Tags: 16.04, apt, do-release-upgrade

I cannot seem to be able to update libstdc++6. I suspect some PPA installed it and now I cannot get ride of it.

Any help?

```
; sudo apt upgrade gcc g++ cpp build-essential                                 
Reading package lists... Done                                                   
Building dependency tree                                                        
Reading state information... Done                                               
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.                    
The following packages have unmet dependencies.                                 
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) but 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~12.04 is installed                                                             
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

and

```
; sudo apt remove gcc-5-base                                                    
Reading package lists... Done                                                   
Building dependency tree                                                        
Reading state information... Done                                               
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:                    
The following packages have unmet dependencies.                                 
 gcj-5-jre-lib : Depends: gcc-5-base (>= 5.2.1-23) but it is not going to be installed                                                                          
 libgcj16 : Depends: gcc-5-base (>= 5.2.1-23) but it is not going to be installed                                                                               
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) but it is not going to be installed                                                               
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and

```
; sudo apt-get -f install                                                       
Reading package lists... Done                                                   
Building dependency tree                                                        
Reading state information... Done                                               
Correcting dependencies... failed.                                              
The following packages have unmet dependencies.                                 
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) but 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~12.04 is installed                                                             
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.                                                                    
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

PS: This is weird: `lsb_release -a` says that I am running `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS`. However, I just did an upgrade to 18.04… Which I think just upgraded to 16… That kinda makes sense. Tags edited.

Answer (score 1):

I appeared to have worked it out:

1. [Download the package for libstdc++.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libstdc++6)
2. Downgrade gcc via `apt-get install gcc-5-base=5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10`.
3. Install manually: `dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1\~16.04.10_amd64.deb`.

At least the errors have gone away.